# How to have a macro search for a value in an offset cell on one sheet in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

this is my first question so please bear with me if i'm doing anything wrong.

Quick back storey... on sheet "Purchase" in column C i want the item name of what has been purchased, in column D i want the quantity and in column G i want the location of where the item is going. For example i want 10 boxes of tiles delivered to the office. C2=Tiles, D2=10, G2=Office

When the location of an item is entered into column G(cell change) i want the macro to offset to the same row in column C and then search for the value in column A on sheet "Office", i currently have this for searching if a cell changes;

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim keycells As String
keycells = "g2:g9999"
If Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(keycells)) = "Office" Then MsgBox "hello"

End Sub
```

This does work, but it also checks if all other cells change, which i dont want it to do this. In place of "msgbox "hello" " i want to put the script for it to offset to the same row in column C look at the value and then search for this value in column A on sheet "Office".

If it is found i need the macro to add the newly purchased quantity to the current quantity on sheet "Office" (this will be column B), if it is not found i need it add the information from columns C & D on sheet "Purchase" to columns A & B

Also i will need to add more locations to the script and will give these locations a sheet in the workbook over time

If this is possible i will be extremely gratefull for all help provided

Comment: Look for the `.Find` method of the Worksheet object - it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @citizenkong unfortunately i haven't found a way to implement that and have it actually work i did attempt: 
    Sub Office_test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purchase")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:="cell", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            aCell.Value = "Test"
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Worksheet_Change` event fires on all cell changes.

To prevent your code running unless the cell is in column G, you could restrict it like this:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim keycells As String
Dim iSect

If target.Column = 7 Then
    keycells = "g2:g9999"
    Set iSect = Application.Intersect(target, Range(keycells))
    If Not iSect Is Nothing Then
        If lcase(target) = "office" Then
            MsgBox "hello"
            ' add code here to copy the data
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

However, a better solution might be to use formulas (such as an array formula or using INDEX and MATCH) in the target worksheets to extract the data - this will avoid using a macro entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much for this script, as you said it would it has stopped the code running on the rest of the sheet. Are you able to help me with now offsetting the cell and finding the value in another sheet?